# Capture video with alpha channel using canvas.captureStream()

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, mediarecorder-api

I'm trying to capture the contents of a canvas element with alpha channel. When I do it I get the RGB values correctly but the Alpha channel seems to get dropped when playing back the resulting video. Is there a way to achieve this?

I'm running the following code:

```
var stream = canvas.captureStream(60);
var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', finishCapturing);
recorder.addEventListener('stop', function(e) {
    video.oncanplay = video.play;
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(blobs, {type:"video/webm; codecs=vp9"}));
});
startCapturing();
recorder.start();
```

Here's a plnkr demonstrating the issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/z3UL9ikmn6PtVoAHvY0B?p=preview

Comment: what video format supports transparency?

Comment: @dandavis webm does support alpha. The problem here is that for the recorder to record and encode fast enough as well as making small sizes, I would guess they dropped support for the alpha channel (IIRC only Blink browsers support playback of those anyways).

Comment: good to know, go blink, but it does what it does, and at this point, we are lucky to be able to make a video at all. Give it time, and don't pull your hair out looking; afaik, this can't be done.

Comment: As a side comment, Cr should support recording video with alpha channel, filled in https://crbug.com/690968 to request it -- I dare to suggest we all star it so it gets prioritized :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no options to enable (VP8/9 transparency channel) from the MediaRecorder API.
One could maybe open an issue on the W3C [Mediacapture-Record](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-record) git repo.

For this, I can guess a few reasons :

- From what I understand, webm alpha channel is grossly an hack from chrome, and is not really implemented in the codec itself, nor completely stabilized.
- MediaRecorder should be able to encode in many formats even if current implementations only support video webm/VP8 and webm/VP9 (chrome only). So it would mean that they would have to somehow keep the alpha channel in the raw stream, only for this new `canvas.captureStream` method. Historically, MediaStream mainly came from getUserMedia interface, and there were no need way of getting transparency from there.
  *[edit: [Specs](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/#html-canvas-element-media-capture-extensions) have changed since this answer was written, and MediaStreams should now keep the alpha channel, even if the consumer may not be able to use it, also Chrome now supports more video codecs.]*
- Chrome, which is the only one to support YUVA webm display in its stable channel (FF supports it in nightly 54), [is still not able to include the `duration`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012) inside their recorded files, let's them fix this before adding the hackish `alpha_mode=true`.

However, you can achieve it yourself *kind of* easily :

If you really want a transparent webm file (only readable in chrome and FF nightly), you can use a second canvas to do the recording, set its background (using `fillRect`) to a chroma that won't appear elsewhere in your drawings, draw the original one on it and record its stream. Once recorded, use ffmpeg to reencode the recorded video, this time with the alpha channel :

```
// all #00FF00 pixels will become transparent.
ffmpeg -i in.webm -c:v libvpx -vf "chromakey=0x00ff00:0.1:0.1,format=yuva420p" -auto-alt-ref 0 out.webm
```

<sup>I personally needed the `-auto-alt-ref 0` flag, not sure everyone needs it though</sup>

But because of this [other chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=653548), you'll actually have to append this other canvas on screen too, and hide it with css (`opacity: 0; width:0px; height:0px;` should do).

#### TL;DR

**This API's implementations are far from being stabilized, no one has made the request for such a feature yet, it may come in near future though, and can be done server-side for the time being.**

Comment: Can you please detail this affirmation: "draw the original one on it"? Thank you.

Comment: @TelmoMarques `recordingContext.fillStyle =uniqueColor; recordingContext.fillRect(0,0,visibleCanvas.width,visbleCanvas.height); recordingContext.drawImage(visibleCanvas, 0,0);`

Comment: Thank you! Is this suppose to work with animations? I had to put `drawImage()` inside a `setInterval()` to draw all the frames, but this results in some sloppy animation (due to `clearRect()` being called before `drawImage()`.

Comment: Forget about it, using `requestAnimationFrame()` instead of `setInterval()` solved the issue!